# Stack<T> implements ICollection, but has methods from ICollection<T>

Tags: .net, stack, generic-collections, interface-implementation

I'm trying to create a custom collection based on `Stack<T>`.  When I look at `Stack<T>` [from metadata] in visual studio, it shows that `Stack<T>` implements `ICollection`, which would require it to implement `ICollection`'s `CopyTo(Array array, index)` method, but instead, it is shown as having `ICollection<T>`'s `CopyTo(T[] array, index)` method.  Can someone explain why this is the case?

I'm trying to create a collection that mimics `Stack<T>` pretty heavily. When I implement `ICollection` as stack does, it requires me to use the `CopyTo(Array array, index)` method, but what I *really* want is to use the `CopyTo(T[] array, index)` method, like `Stack<T>` does.  Is there a way to achieve this without implementing `ICollection<T>`?

Comment: The methods are implemented explicitly.  Explicitly implemented methods are not public and therefore would not show up in the metadata (which only lists public properties).

Comment: You might try .NET Reflector to see the actual complete source code of `Stack<T>`, including private methods.

Comment: @JeffMercado Wow... I can't believe it was that easy.  I always wondered what "Explicitly Implement suchnsuch" meant.  Thanks.

Comment: Posted the .NET 4.0 implementation of Stack<T> if you want to take a look. http://pastebin.com/p2k4URtU

Comment: @SPFiredrake, how did you get that?!

Comment: @JeffMercado you should probably post that as an answer and briefly explain how to explicitly implement an interface so you can get the credit.

Comment: @JeffMercado - your answer, which is good, is more useful as an answer than a comment. Strangely, I've seen more and more people use comments to answer questions lately. Go figure.

Comment: @C.E: I'm swamped at work right now and would have otherwise provided a full answer.  The best that I could do with the time I have is to throw in a comment.  It's hard to force myself to put in a sub-standard answer (by my standards).

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - downloading Framework source from within VS has been around for a while. Take a look at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rscc/archive/2010/08/16/net-framework-4-reference-source-is-available.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have written, you can use explicit interface implementation to satisfy your non-generic interface:

```
void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int arrayIndex)
{
  var arrayOfT = array as T[];
  if (arrayOfT == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
  CopyTo(arrayOfT, arrayIndex); // calls your good generic method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the method `CopyTo(Array array, index)` is implemented explicitly. This means, you will only see that method if you see the object as an ICollection:

```
var collection = (ICollection)stack;
collection.CopyTo(array, 0);
```