# What does Queue<T> actually implement

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

While attempting to implement my own Queue by wrapping  the generic Queue, I noticed that Queue implements ICollection. However, the method signature of ICollection.CopyTo is as follows

```
void CopyTo(
    Array array,
    int index)
```

Whereas the method signature of the generic Queue.CopyTo is

```
public void CopyTo(
    T[] array, 
    int arrayIndex)
```

This is the same as the signature of the generic version of ICollection.CopyTo. My confusion comes from the fact that the generic queue doesn't seem to implement the generic ICollection, but instead implements the standard ICollection. So what exactly is going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Stack Implements ICollection, but has methods from ICollection<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589803/c-sharp-stack-implements-icollection-but-has-methods-from-icollectiont)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx):

```
public class Queue<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

So it implements the *generic* `IEnumerable<T>` interface, but the *non-generic* `ICollection` interface.

Don't let the similarity of the names fool you - `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>` are entirely separate interfaces, and while something like this (implementing some generic interfaces but only non-generic other interfaces) is unusual, it's entirely legitimate.

I suspect that there were various aspects of `ICollection<T>` which the designers *really* didn't want to support in `Queue<T>`, but equally they wanted to implement `ICollection` to allow folks to upgrade from the non-generic [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) class painlessly.

EDIT: As noted in Dennis's answer, [`ICollection.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.copyto.aspx) is implemented explicitly in `Queue<T>`. This means that you can *only* get to that signature via an expression of type `ICollection`. For example:

```
Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
Array array = new Button[10];
queue.CopyTo(array, 0, queue.Count); // Compilation failure...
ICollection collection = (ICollection) queue;
collection.CopyTo(array, 0, queue.Count); // Compiles, but will go bang
```

The method taking a strongly typed array *would* be valid to implement [`ICollection<T>.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx), but the `Add` and `Remove` methods of `ICollection<T>` aren't present - instead, you're meant to `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` values.

Comment: [Gosh, these interfaces are a collective headache.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IncrediblyLamePun)

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes. I'd enumerate the difficulties, but I'm too lazy.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but it *only* answers the *title* of the question. The answer to the question about the two different signatures is given in [Dennis Traub's  answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12826832/1106367).

Answer (score 4):

Queue has its own CopyTo() implementation and it *explicitly* implements ICollection.CopyTo(), according to the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Because `ICollection<T>` contains a `Remove` method that removes an item *from any place in the collection*.  This is not applicable to a Queue since you can only remove the top item without rebuilding the entire queue.